# Script to move to next image

Tags: php, html, image, photos

I am writing a script to display images on my site. The images are stored on the server and the source (path) is on a mySQL database. I want to be able to move to the next (or previous picture) by invoking two php functions I have made to do so. The code I have written so far is:

```
<?php

require "db_connection.php";

$query="SELECT source FROM photos";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$count=0;
$numberofpics=mysql_num_rows($result);

$image=mysql_result($result, $count, "source");


$num=1;

function slideshowForward() {
$num=$num+1;
if($num==($numberofpics+1)) {
$num=1;
}
$count=$count+1;
$image=mysql_result($result, $count, "source");
}

function slideshowBack() {
$num=$num-1;
if ($num==0) {
$num=$numberofpics;
}
$count=$count-1;
$image=mysql_result($result, $count, "source");
}
?>
```

The html portion to display the images is:

```
<!-- FORWARD AND BACK FUNCTIONS-->

<a class="back" href="http://mywebsite.com/discoverandrank.php?function=slideshowBack()">         <img src="graphics/back.png"/></a>

<a class="next" href="http://mywebsite.com/discoverandrank.php?   function=slideshowForward()"><img src="graphics/forward.png"/></a>

<!--DISPLAY MIDDLE PHOTO-->

<div id="thepics">
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/<?php echo $image; ?>" name="mypic" border=0   height="300" width="500"></img>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure that the php script is incrementing/decrementing the count currently for the image, but I think the problem might be because the html (specifically img src="....")  part is not re-evaluated when the count of the image increases?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm there are two things to point out here:

1. I think that passing a function name as a parameter on an action is not a good idea, instead you should user something like: "http://mywebsite.com/discoverandrank.php?op=next&current=10" and then evaluate the op and current value to take some action.
2. For gettting the next picture from database you could use something like this:
   "Select source FROM photos LIMIT "current+1" , 1"
3. For gettting the previous picture from database you could use something like this:
   "Select source FROM photos LIMIT "current-1" , 1"

This way you dont need to keep counters and stuff, just have to check if those queries return any data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what does the phrase after the "?" refer to? (op=next&current=10)

Comment: op=next&current=10 means that in your php you can acccess them as $_GET["op"] and $_GET["current"], so then you can do something like: if(isset($_GET["op"]) && ($_GET["op"] == "next"){ calculateNext(); }